# Meteor mup deploy error

Tags: meteor, deployment, mup

I am continuously getting this error on meteor app deployment using mup deploy command. 
mup setup command is working just fine. When mup deploy starts, it executes many commands and reach to a command where it says
'minifying app code'. It stays there for 5-6 mins and then this error occurs.

**What can be causing this error and how to resolve this?**

```
 mup deploy --verbose

Building App Bundle Locally
   Minifying app code
=> Build Error. Check the logs printed above.
Error: build-error
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/mup/lib/modules/meteor/build.js:46:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
```

Here is my mup.js file.
Other stats
node v7.7.2
npm  v4.1.2

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      // TODO: set host address, username, and authentication method
      host: '54.218.35.182',
      username: 'ubuntu',
      pem: '~/.ssh/iAssureIT-Ubuntu2.pem'
      // password: 'server-password'
      // or neither for authenticate from ssh-agent
    }
  },

  meteor: {
    // TODO: change app name and path
    name: 'musissive',
    path: '/var/www/meteor/musissive',

    servers: {
      one: {},
    },

    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },

    env: {
      // TODO: Change to your app's url
      // If you are using ssl, it needs to start with https://
      ROOT_URL: 'http://musifyindia.com',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor',
      PORT: 3003,
    },

    docker: {
      // change to 'kadirahq/meteord' if your app is not using Meteor 1.4
      image: 'abernix/meteord:base',
    },

    // This is the maximum time in seconds it will wait
    // for your app to start
    // Add 30 seconds if the server has 512mb of ram
    // And 30 more if you have binary npm dependencies.
    deployCheckWaitTime: 2400,

    // Show progress bar while uploading bundle to server
    // You might need to disable it on CI servers
    enableUploadProgressBar: true
  },

  mongo: {
    port: 27017,
    version: '3.4.1',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Please what version of meteor are you trying to deploy? And do have have mongodb installed on your aws server as well?

Answer (score 1):

The error happening in meteor build had nothing to do with MUP.js. The issue was with low RAM on server. I was trying the build with free EC2 instance whihc has max 1 GB available. This is not sufficient for Meteor Build. When I upgraded to 4 GB instance, it started working just fine.

Comment: 1GB RAM broke in same way. 2GB works for me! Meteor 1.8